# Same program different output for c# and c

Tags: c#, c

I have written a function to calculate checksum in two different programming languages. In `c` and `c#`. But I am getting different outputs on both sides. the program written in `c` is giving the correct output. But the program written in `c#` is giving unexpected output.

**C Code**

```
uint16_t findOnesComplement (uint16_t data)       {
    return ~data;
}

uint16_t findTwosComplement (uint16_t data)       {
    return (findOnesComplement(data) + 1);
}

uint8_t calculateCheckSum (uint8_t* data, uint8_t dataLen)                {
    uint16_t sum = '1' + '1' + 'V' + '1' + '?';
    uint16_t val = 0x00;

    val = findTwosComplement(sum);

    return (((val & 0xFF) & 0x7F) | 0x40);

}
```

> > Returns output as 0x58. Which is correct.

**C# code**

```
    public UInt16 findOnesComplement(UInt16 data)        {
        return (UInt16)~data;
    }

    public UInt16 findTwosComplement(UInt16 data)        {
        return (UInt16)(findOnesComplement(data) + 1);
    }

    public byte calculateCheckSum()        {
        UInt16 sum = '1' + '1' + 'V' + '1' + '?';
        UInt16 val = 0;
        byte retVal = 0;

        val = findTwosComplement(sum);
        retVal = (byte)(((val & 0xFF) & 0x7F) | 0x40);
        return retVal;
    }
```

> > gives the output as 0x88. Which is not what I expected.

**EDIT**

```
    public int calculateCheckSum()        {
        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
        string str = "11V1?";
        int sum = 0;
        Byte[] encodedBytes = ascii.GetBytes(str);
        foreach (Byte b in encodedBytes)
        {
            Console.Write("[{0}]", b);
            sum += b;

        }
        int val = 0;

        val = findTwosComplement(sum);
        return  (((val & 0xFF) & 0x7F) | 0x40);
    }
```

Have edited the code a bit for making sure everything is in ascii and the return statement is an expression same as `c` as per comments.

> > return 88 which is wrong.

Any suggestons?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? At which step does C# start giving different intermediate results to the C?

Comment: Are you sure that the C# program uses ASCII encoding for all their characters, and that adding characters in C# just adds the ASCII-encoded values like what happens in C?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, I am not sure about the ASCII encoding part. But I need all the values to be in ASCII. How can I encode it to ASCII?

Comment: It can have something to do with the cast and the encapsulation of the return value into an own variable instead of to return the result of an expression. I don't know C#, but why you changed that part in the C# code? Does C# doesn't allow expressions as return values?

Comment: @chux No, C# chars are 16-bit, and they get promoted to ints for addition anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude see the edit. I have changed the programs as per your comments but the output is same

Comment: @RobertS supports Monica Cellio I have changed the programs as per your comments but the output is same

Comment: @DevjeetMandal `(((val & 0xFF) & 0x7F) | 0x40)` is curious.  Why the unneeded `& 0xFF`?  It there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @canton7 I am not able to debug in visual studio. As my project is winform and I am not getting how to debug it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No The checksum values after addition will be `16bit` or more. But I need to convert it to `8bit` value. So I am doing `(val & 0xFF)` to eliminate the upper 8bits.

Comment: I've run the C# code and I get the answer as 88 decimal = 0x58. Are you printing the output correctly as hex?

Comment: It's time you create a proper [mcve], which includes the actual call to `calculateCheckSum` and how you print or report the result. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Rup Thanks. I was printing decimal and expecting hex. Sorry.

Comment: Note: "But I need to convert it to 8bit value. So I am doing (val & 0xFF) to eliminate the upper 8bits" --> The `val & 0x7F` also bring it into the range of an 8bit value.  IAC< looks like the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get 0x58 (which is 88 decimal) for both

sum = 296 (49*3 + 86 + 63) = 296 = 0000 0001 0010 1000

Twos complement = 1111 1110 1101 0111 + 1 = 1111 1110 1101 1000

Masking with 0xFF = 1101 1000 = 216 = 0xD8

0xD8 & 0x7F = 0x58 = 88 dec (the `| 0x40` gives the same result)

My guess is you aren't formatting the result correctly